# How to install nav2d packages

Tags: ros, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the nav2d from http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d by using: sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-nav2d
and then I have to install additional packages, but it dos not work!
I use for example:   sudo apt-get install stage_ros
but get this output:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package stage_ros

Can anyone help to how can I install these packages ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225013/how-to-install-nav2d-packages/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not install dependencies manually. By using "apt-get install" all dependencies should be installed on your system. The correct package name for Stage is ros-indigo-stage-ros.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-01-26**:
From Synaptic Package Manager was p2os_urdf package missing. Now I can run the simulator but it shows the error. `ERROR: cannot launch node of type [p2os_urdf/p2os_publisher_3at]: can't locate node [p2os_publisher_3at] in package [p2os_urdf]`

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-01-26**:
p2os_urdf is optional, because it's not released into indigo. You can either get the source code from github, or just uncomment the part from the launch file. (It's only used to show the pioneer-model in RVIZ)